# How to add border radius to next js image?

Tags: next.js

i have problem with Next.js image component when i add objectFit="cover" to Image my border radius disappears. can anyone help?

Comment: You can apply it either via `styles` prop or `className`.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use `overflow: hidden` on the div wrapping the image:

```js
<div style={{borderRadius: '5px', overflow: 'hidden'}}>
  <Image src="..." layout="fill" objectFit="cover" />
</div>
```

Comment: works for me when I make sure the wrapping div is positioned relatively

Comment: both `layout` and `objectFit` properties are depreciated

Answer (score 2):

you can add a class to your image and change css in global css.
beware you can not change your class attribute in jsx css or inline style

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer worked for me for the image itself but when I used `placeholder="blur"` with `blurDataURL="..."` the position of the placeholder was a little bit off and it got cut off. What I ended up doing is defined the size of the wrapper explicitly which was equal to the image size:

```html
<div style={{ borderRadius: '50%', overflow: 'hidden', width: '48px', height: '48px' }}>
  <Image
    src="..."
    objectFit="cover"
    width="48"
    height="48"
    placeholder="blur"
    blurDataURL={data:image/...}
  />
</div>
```

Comment: Width and height cannot be passed as a string with px on it, as the expected value must be in numeric and strings are not allowed.

Comment: Good catch, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2):

```js
import Image from "next/image";

function Img(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <div // wrap your Image tag
        className="flex h-[18px] w-[18px]" // here is Tailwind
        style={{
          position: "relative",
          // width: "18px", // but you can use CSS
          // height: "18px", // and select size here
        }}
      >
        <Image
          src={
            "/someAwesomeImage"
          }
          alt="image"
          fill
          style={{
            objectFit: "cover",
            borderRadius: "100px", // and here you can select border radius
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export { Img };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add **className="rounded-full"**

Ex:

```js
<Image src="..." layout="fixed" className="rounded-full"/>
```

**EDIT:** I realized that I was using Tailwind CSS at the time I wrote this answer. You can use `overflow:hidden` as mentioned in the accepted answer

Comment: this post is misleading! Where is that "rounded-full" class coming? Next image does not have build-in classes

Comment: It's tailwind class, and that's not installed by default. Please revise this answer

Answer (score 0):

With MUI:

This is a component that returned an Image with style.
The layout should be "responsive" and the width & height properties of Image will calculated after loading.

```js
    import * as React from 'react';
    import Image from 'next/image';
    import { Box } from '@mui/material';
    
    export default function CustomImage(props) {
      const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = React.useState();
      const [width, setWidth] = React.useState(0);
      const [height, setHeight] = React.useState(0);
    
      const { src } = props;
    
      React.useEffect(() => {
        src && setSelectedImage(src);
      }, [src]);
    
      return (
        <Box
          sx={{
            position: 'relative',
            width: '100%',
            textAlign: 'center',
            borderRadius: '0.6rem',
            overflow: 'hidden',
          }}
        >
          {selectedImage && (
            <Image
              layout="responsive"
              width={width}
              height={height}
              objectFit="contain"
              src={selectedImage}
              onLoad={({ target }) => {
                const { naturalWidth, naturalHeight } = target;
                setHeight(naturalHeight);
                setWidth(naturalWidth);                
              }}
            />
          )}
        </Box>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

with MUI:

You can do with a CSS nested trick.

```js
const containerStyle = {
   ...,

   img: {
     border: '2px solid #900 !important' // this is the trick
   }
}

<Box sx={containerStyle}>
   <Image .... />
</Box>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).